# In BIRT, how do I access an arbitrary data set from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, reporting, birt

I am building my first report in [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/).

Very quickly I ran into a problem in which I wanted to display some text or data based on an expression that included data from two different tables (not tables that can/should be joined - (hypothetically example- take a student's ACT score from his record in the student table and compare it against the statistics table's entry for ACT statistics).  I soon realized that a data element has to be bound to a dataset (only one of them.)

I found a [similar question](http://eclipsezone.net/eclipse/forums/m92006973.html) in the BIRT mailing list which helped me get to a solution - I can bind an individual data element to a different dataset, but it can still access the elements of its container.  I can send a parameters to the dataset that the element is bound to (e.g. "ACT" in the example I mentioned above).

Eventually however, I came to a place where I needed to use data from three different tables.  I am stuck here, and I'm assuming that there is a way to do this through the scripting abilities, but I have yet to see in the documentation a way to extract data from a data set - everything I have dealt with so far is associated with binding a report element to a dataset.

To be clear, I have seen that I can add JavaScript functions to the initialize section of the top level report (and call them from an expression in a data element) but I don't see how in a script I can query any of my datasets -- as opposed to only interacting with the dataset bound to my data element).

How can I access an arbitrary (though already defined) data set from JavaScript in BIRT?  (Or how can I access more than two datasets from an element - one that it is bound to, and one that its container is bound to?)

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried to do this for a while.  The immediate answer that pops to mind is that you need to put the third data set into a table (can have visibility set to false) and you would need to populate the table values to a GlobalValue.  Then you could get at the GlobalValues from the data control through script.

I know that it is not pretty.  I will have a look over the weekend and see if 2.3 has added any functionality that makes this easier.

Comment: I wondered if I could do something like that (bind an element to the datum I need, make it invisible) - but I thought that surely with all the scripting capabilities that seem to exist, there must be a better way!  I would appreciate hearing anything you learn.

Comment: If that does end up being the route, is there going to be a way to easily "query" the table to get the cell I want?  This table could be pretty large so I don't know if this will actually be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
 this.getValue()
```

which will return the current column's binding value instead of

```
 dataSetRow["RUN"]
```